# How to copy a rectangle from one image to another with different resolution images

Tags: c#, css, image

I have few rectangles drawn on one image and I want to import the same rectangles on the other image.
I have the height and width of both images and coordinates of all the rectangles.
I need to adjust the coordinates of the rectangle before importing so their position remains same with respect to the image.
I just need some direction how to proceed. Please help..

Comment: Is this related to `css` or `gdi+`?

Answer (score 0):

One idea: calculate a scaling factor based on the relative size of both images, then apply that scale factor to each point of every rectangle.

Some pseudocode for a better undestanding (I hope):

```
xfactor <- image1.width / image0.width
yfactor <- image1.height / image0.height

for each r in rectangles:
    r.p0.x <- r.p0.x * xfactor
    r.p0.y <- r.p0.y * yfactor
    r.p1.x <- r.p1.x * xfactor
    r.p1.y <- r.p1.y * yfactor
end
```